# Trigger a url refresh with ui-router and transitionservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have an issue with ui-router . My url is replaced but the page is not reloading.
I work with "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.26", "angular": "~1.5.11",

My code is in my $stateProvider resolve

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function (transition) {

options.forEach((options) => {
    api
        .load()
        .then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                const currentUrl = $location.absUrl();
                let updatedUrl = currentUrl;
                response.data.forEach((element) => {
                    if (element) {
                        const regex = new RegExp(`'${element}~`);

                        if (updatedUrl.match(regex)) {
                            updatedUrl = updatedUrl.replaceAll(
                                `'${element.data}~`,
                                `'${element.data.plam}~`
                            );
                        }

                    }
                });
                if (updatedUrl !== currentUrl) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $window.location.href = updatedUrl;
                    });
                }

            }
        });
});
```

});